# In the database, why can't we just use "Long" integers for dates (millis since epoch)

Tags: java, database, epoch

I would like to use a Long datatype in the database to represent dates (as millis since epoch). The reason why, is that storing dates is so complex with the jdbc driver and Oracle engine. If you submit the wrong datatype in preparedStatement it casts a timestamp to a date (or vice versa) blowing your index, resulting in full table scans in the worst case scenario. 
I can't remember the details, but I know that there are details to remember. I don't want to have to remember details. It seems like just storing dates as long (millis since epoch) would work here just fine and I have nothing to remember.

Note, I feel that a time zone is merely presentational. It should never be stored in the first place. Most companies have a policy of only using UTC, but once again, that is just more information to know. Let's all just store the number of milliseconds since epoch, and upon display show the user the millis formatted to THEIR particular time zone.

EDIT: 
It just seems like millions of dollars in bugs and wasted productivity/confusion revolve around time zones and date formatting, along with crazy jdbc driver date conversion/casting. Let's do away with it once and for all.

I realize now that another reason against doing what I suggest, is that we may want to save space in the db. In that case we can have decaseconds or even simply "seconds" since epoch. To whichever degree you would like to save space.

Answer (score 2):

You **can** use integers or some other appropriate type to represent date/time values in your database.  However it does introduce a couple of problems:

- All of your current and future (!!!) applications (Java or otherwise) that use the database tables need to convert between database integers and date/time values.
- If your SQL queries, SQL stored procedures or SQL triggers involve the relevant columns, they may need to do the conversions.  That makes them more complicated / hard to get right.  Furthermore, the extra complexity could cause the query engine to fall back to a slower way of executing your query ... because the query optimizer doesn't understand what you are doing.
- Using integers to represent dates will make it harder for people to do ad-hoc SQL queries against the table that involve the date columns.

**EDIT**

Whether you save space by representing dates as integers is database specific.  IIRC, Oracle stores date/time values as a primitive integers.  And I expect any decent RDBMS would do the same ... both for storage space and query efficiency.

Storing date/time values as integers does not address timezone issue.  This is a fundamentally complicated problem.

- In some cases you want a date or date/time to represent an absolute point in time.
- In other cases, you want it to represent a point in time relative to the geographical location / timezone in which some event occurred.
- In other cases, you want to represent the time relative to the location of the system, or of the user.

Then there is the question of granularity.  (Using ISO date syntax for clarity) does "1999" mean the same thing as "1999-01-01" or "1999-01-01T00:00:00"?  And what about sub-second precision?

The point is that no simple SQL date/time (or integer) representation can deal with all of this.  The root cause of the bugs/issues/difficulties we see is programmers taking shortcuts in their implementation and (more importantly) being sloppy in their thinking.

**EDIT 2**

There is still the issue that many problems still arise due to differences in the way that various databases and their respective JDBC drivers handle date literals and assumptions about timezones.  I'm not an expert on JDBC and the SQL standard(s) but the root problems seem to be:

- Database vendors have not fully implemented the datetime types as specified in (for example) SQL-92.
- The SQL standards don't specify a single syntax for datetime literals, but allow database vendor specific syntaxes.
- The SQL standards allow the timezone to be defaulted, without any standard way to specify (or even find out) what it defaults to.  More vendor-specific solutions.
- The JDBC specification doesn't provide a way for an application to get or set the default timezone, or select date-time literal syntaxes.

All of this adds up to a mess of portability and configuration issues for the Java developer.  However, I don't think it is significantly worse than the portability and
configuration problems we get with other aspects of Java / RDBMS applications.  And by ditching datetime types entirely, you'd be buying into a bunch of other problems; see above.

Comment: It sounds like what you are claiming is that sometimes we want to represent an event occurring at a point in time with respect to a particular location.
I claim that what you *really* want to store is two pieces of information. 1. The actual time that the event occurred and 2. the location that it occurred at. Mixing the two into one field is tantamount (and sometimes equivalent) to mixing the view with the model. A time is a time is a time, regardless of where this time happened. That's the beauty/nature of time, it exists outside of space (well, kind of.. hehe)

Comment: *"I claim that what you really want to store is two pieces of information."* - Well more than that.  You also need to know whether the date/time value refers to a point in time or a period (e.g. a year, day, second) and the precision of the point.  Neither of these is adequately represented by the SQL types ... as implemented by typical DB vendors.  But the REAL problem is stopping thicko developers from taking shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

I do this all the time.  The practice has been quite verbally criticized to me repeatedly.  I have defended this practice though as my systems (e.g.) have survived DST changes (secondary airline reservation systems) where other systems performing DST-boundary, international or Arizona flight duration calcs have failed miserably.  Date arithmetic (not necessarily calendar arithmetic) becomes significantly easier.

It is trivial in nearly every major programming/web language to convert for display.  In fact the integerial unix epoch date can be pushed directly to a web page and allow JavaScript to translate into local time avoiding intermediate conversion.

The only place this does not work well is in Calendar arithmetic:  Add *1 month* to 31 January.

Answer (score 1):

On reason I can think of is to store date and times previous to Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT.

I feel your pain though. Oracle date/datetime treatment is painful in JDBC. It is even inconsistent among different versions of the drivers!

I have to say that I haven't found much problems in other JDBC drivers (other DB vendors) though...

Comment: Yes. Case in point: date of birth. There are still plenty of people born before 1970. ;)

Comment: Yes, although there are some Dinosaurs still around, we can use negative numbers to represent their age correctly. The semantics of "millis since epoch" still applies to time before the epoch. 

-1 seconds "since" the epoch is equivalent to saying 1 second "before" the epoch. 

But thanks, I forgot to check out this use case!

Answer (score 1):

Now problem at all.

Unless you need some query which contains some calculation on the date column, in that case, the database needs to have a date type that it understands.

You probably don't need that, so you can use any representation you like.

Comment: Agreed, there's no reason you can't use an integer column for times. One concern might writing your own functions to convert it to minutes/hours/days/weeks/etc, but that's all relatively simple.

Answer (score 1):

Just store the UTC long (Big Integer), and make the DB column name indicate it is holding the `millis_since_epoch` (could use comment as well but I'm not certain all DB's support comments).  This way you can move the data to any DB without concern, the data can be safely interpreted outside the app that created it (this is why the DB column name is so important), and you can handle presentation/zone however you need via UI.

Answer (score 0):

What's the question? Are you asking if it's possible? That would depend on which database you're using, but I assume it's possible with most. I've definitely done that with SQL lite in Android apps (which are programmed in Java, if you aren't familiar with it).

Answer (score 0):

The only problem of not using the date data type is you may have to do conversions in your app from the Long value to a date if you need to do things like comparing dates.  You can store data anyway you like, the presentation layer is where it might become more problematic and require additional code.  For example, populating components like a calendar.

Comment: Yes, but I suppose that my argument was that the presentation layer is where this calculation *belongs*. 
The time zone, actually includes no information, other than the fact that a user likes to view a time in a particular "format". But that should be configured on the presentation layer. 
Do you agree?